# How to get GNOME to stop asking for a password everytime I insert a dvd

Tags: gnome, authentication

Hello I set up a ubuntu server (22.04.1) with plex running and gnome (42.4)

This is working really well.  However, everytime I put a dvd in, it asks me for a password.  it is driving me crazy.  The user logged in is listed as a administrator.

Any idea how to turn that off?

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to add your user to the `cdrom` group with `usermod -G cdrom $USER`.
The `polkit` rule below allows users in the `cdrom` group to mount CD/DVD.

```
# cat /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/01-dvd.rules
/* Allow members of the cdrom group to mount /dev/sr[0] devices */
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount")
    {
        var device = action.lookup("device");
        if (device === "/dev/sr0")
        {
            if (subject.isInGroup("cdrom"))
            {
                return polkit.Result.YES;
            } else {
                return polkit.Result.NO;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

To test this rule:

- create the rule file `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/01-dvd.rules`
- restart the Polkit service: `systemctl restart polkit.service`
- log off and on again
- insert CD/DVD

More information [in this link](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3148751).

Comment: This worked.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad this worked. Please upvote the answer and mark it as a solution. Thanks.